# Вхождение числа в массив

Tags: c++, массивы

Помогите исправить ошибку в функции.

Она должна давать значение 1 переменной bool, если число хоть раз входит в массив, и 0, если число не входит.

```
bool vhod(int a, int b[], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
        if (a == b[i])
            return true;
        break;
      if (a != b[i] && i == n-1 && vhod == 0)
            return false;
 }
}
```

При входных данных:

```
a = 7  
n = 3  
b[] = {0, 5, 14}  
Vhod = 1
```

Что не правильно?

Comment: Ваш `break` выполняется безусловно на первой же итерации. Из-за этого возвращаемое значение не определено, так как нет соответствующего `return`. То, что функция вернула вам единицу — чистая случайность.

Comment: @Arhad, как тогда исправить?

Comment: @Alone_Fox убрать его и все условие "if (a != b[i]...", а за циклом - return false добавить

Comment: @Alone_Fox, `bool vhod(int a, int b[], int n) { bool found = false; for (size_t i = 0; i < n && !found; i++)  found = (a == b[i]); return found;}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы уже вышли из цикла - то, значит, ничего не найдено. Что вы еще хотите проверять?...

```
bool vhod(int a, int b[], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) if (a == b[i]) return true;
    return false;
}
```